# android scale bitmap to screen dimension

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

actually I'm trying to create simple app with wallpapers.

I'm trying to scale my image to user device screen size.
I'm using code like bellow:

```
/*

  DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 

  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 

  int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
  int width = metrics.widthPixels; 

*/


Display metrics = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

int height = metrics.getHeight();
int width = metrics.getWidth(); 
float fourToThree;
int wymiar;
Bitmap mbitmap; //definicja zmiennej przechowującej bitmapę
try {

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), cardBase.cardImages[position]);
    //UP - zapisanie obrazu z tablicy do zmiennej bitmapy
    /*if(height>=width) {
        fourToThree = height * 0.75f;   //height
        wymiar = (int)Math.round(fourToThree);
        mbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, height, wymiar, true);
    } else {    
        fourToThree = height * 0.75f;
        wymiar = (int)Math.round(fourToThree);
        mbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width, wymiar, true);
    }*/
    mbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width, height, true);
    myWallpaper.setBitmap(mbitmap);
    Toast.makeText(SelectedCard.this, "Wallpaper changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(SelectedCard.this, "Sorry, an error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I was trying many other ways but still have my image larger then device screen :(

I'm testing it on `virtual phone` and I was trying to create image dit 160 dpi as a device screen, it's not working too.

Can anyone tell me, how can I scale my image (jpg - 320 x 480 px, 300 dpi) to set it as a wallpaper on device ?

Any ideas ?

thanks :)

Ps. sorry for text mistakes, English is my second language ;p

---

Ok, i have something like that:

imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try
            /*{
                myWallpaper.setResource(HdImageBase.HdImages[position]);
                Toast.makeText(ImageMini.this, "Wallpaper changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/
            {
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 

                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 

                int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
                int width = metrics.widthPixels; 
                float fourToThree;
                int wymiar;
                Bitmap mbitmap; //definicja zmiennej przechowującej bitmapę

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), cardBase.cardImages[position]);

                mbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width, height, true);
                myWallpaper.setBitmap(mbitmap);

                Toast.makeText(SelectedCard.this, "Wallpaper changed \n" + width + "\n" + height, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SelectedCard.this, "Sorry, an error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Width and height values are correct 320 x 480 but image which I'm setting as a wallpaper is still more bigger then my device scren.

After test on my real phone LG L5 with new android (not sure which version). Image is set as wallpaper correct (in portrait mode - 1 image for all 5 "roll screens" without scaling).

How can i tested it on other devices ? 
Mean... is this portrait mode for wallpapers is available only in new android version ?

Comment: Thanks guys but I'm talking about change size of image which will be set as a wallpaper in the phone. I dont want to put it to ImageView :) eg. I have array of images (280 x 320) after tap one of images i setting it as a phone wallpaper (on the main screen - "desktop"). like in this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stobolewski.animalswalpapers&hl=pl

Answer (score 0):

Try this may work :
ImageView property :`android:scaleType=“fitXY”`

Comment: Ok, i have something like that:

Comment: look 3 posts up (i add new comment to my question :/ ).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to scale bitmap to fit a screen:

**1st:**

the follow function draws the specified bitmap, **scaling/translating automatically** to fill the destination rectangle:

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect src, dst;
    int widthOfBitmapSrc, heightOfBitmapSrc;

    widthOfBitmapSrc = mBitmapSrc.getWidth();
    heightOfBitmapSrc = mBitmapSrc.getHeight();
    src = new Rect(0, 0, widthOfBitmapSrc, heightOfBitmapSrc);//size of bitmap

    dst = new Rect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());//size of this view

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapSrc, src, dst, null);//scale bitmap from src to dst
}
```

see this link:[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint))

**2nd:**

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int widthOfNewBitmap, heightOfNewBitmap;

    widthOfNewBitmap = this.getWidth();//width of this view
    heightOfNewBitmap = this.getHeight();//height of this view

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmapSrc, widthOfNewBitmap,heightOfNewBitmap,true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapSrc, 0, 0, null);//copy bitmap to canvas of this view without scale
}
```